# Retrieve WGS 84 from Google map

Tags: google-maps, geo, wgs84

If I have a list of address that is for instance "Keilaranta 17 FI-02150 ESPOO FINLAND" in my sql server database and I want to add a new column to add the data of  WGS 84. You retrieve the  WGS 84 data from google map or similiar. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) API. Effectively you need to provide Google with an address (so in your case Keilaranta 17 FI-02150 ESPOO FINLAND) and the API will return the long and lat in WGS84 (Spherical Mercator).

You will also want to read the [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12) associated with this as storing results for any use other than caching is against the rules laid out without a commercial licence.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can't permanently store coordinates obtained from Google map API, though you can cache for up to 30 days for performance purposes. Here's a link to a similar  stackoverflow question I and others had answered:

[Terms and Conditions Google Maps: Can I store lat/lng and address components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803805/terms-and-conditions-google-maps-can-i-store-lat-lng-and-address-components/20809719#20809719)