# Storing latitude/longitude and place name from google api in db

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

When a user makes a search in my website, the nearby users are displayed. Hence, storing latitude and longitude positions of each user becomes a necessity here. By looking at google terms and conditions, I am not sure if I am allowed to do this. Terms and condition says,

> 10.5.d No caching or storage. You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may
>   store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving
>   the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency
>   (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking
>   usage), and only if such storage: is temporary (and in no event more
>   than 30 calendar days); is secure; does not manipulate or aggregate
>   any part of the Content or Service; and does not modify attribution in
>   any way.

I see a similar question here [Terms and Conditions Google Maps: Can I store lat/lng and address components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803805/terms-and-conditions-google-maps-can-i-store-lat-lng-and-address-components)
There is only one answer to which a few have not agreed to. So I would like to get more opinion on this. Is there any way google can be contacted to get this clarified? Is there any other way to achieve my goal? I wonder what logic is used for websites like offerup.

I also see [in this article](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3) google itself explains how to store address and location information to db. If it is not allowed, I dont think google would have made such an article. Please let me know if someone has done similar storage or got any confirmation from google.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use) not coding.

Comment: @geocodezip the support page in google developer console redirects me to stackoverflow to address any questions. If I am not supposed to ask this here, where can I get the answer from?

Comment: Ask Google.  They are off topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to let this question open. Programming is not just coding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with getting a users coordinates and storing it in your DB as long as you are using google maps API to check for nearby users it should be fine.

Unless you are trying to cheat the service or using the data to compete with google it shouldn't be a problem.