# Worldwide interactive fashion stylish map is impossible with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo, mootools

I have a map designed in Gimp/Adobe. Now i need to use it as background image and put canvas or drawing lines so that on hover i can show map and some properties on it. I need to run it in IE, Chrome, Firefox.

Is there any open-source world-wide interactive map, which can be use for style/fashion based global maping system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html), just google for "google maps v3 custom tiles". See it in action at http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_customTiles.html.

There are also generators of custom tiles or overlays from your bitmaps, e.g. [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/).

Comment: Yes but its not stylish. You can not friendly customize it to look like firefox glow or looks like more sexy.

Comment: Another problem i noticed. When there is not internet how do those MAP works because i have local application which is running indoor buildings without internet.

Comment: Indeed, with you own map tiles (not overlays) and custom map controls, you can customize it to whatever sexy means to you.

Comment: w/o internet access: if you use custom map tiles, you need just GMaps JavaScript Libs, technically it should be of no problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294782/using-google-maps-v3-offline-e-g-with-cache-manifest), but I do not know how it is w/ the license. Other web maps frameworks are listed here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop/Frameworks#Webmaps