# How to open map in offline mode with Ionic cordaova

Tags: dictionary, ionic-framework

I have an application that shows your location with a marker using google map Api and geolocation plugin , it works when THE internet is active.

What i need is to do the same function but without internet  , what are the best approaches to make that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need a sqlite storage
you can install it through  ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
Also Offline maps are a bit involved. I've not implemented one yet myself but was looking into it a while back.
I don't think you can use the native iOS or Android mapping libraries though.
Anyway, here is the basic idea:
You will need to create, download and store a tile set using a tool like MapBox Studio https://www.mapbox.com/design/49 or its predecessor TileMill
and display it in your app using a library like Leaflet18 or MapBox for JS33 (based on Leaflet).
You will need to export the tileset in a format that Leaflet can use - from what I understand there are a couple of ways of doing this, either as an .mbtiles store, which is essentially an sqlite database, or as a folder structure of .png files.
Take a look at these posts for more info for the different methods:

https://kuamoto.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/myth-1-cant-make-offline-apps/

http://davidrs.com/wp/phonegap-3-0-leaflet-offline-maps/77

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkNKoSO9X60

[Using Google Maps V3 offline, e.g. with cache-manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294782/using-google-maps-v3-offline-e-g-with-cache-manifest)

Good luck

Comment: I am already using sqlite storage , but i want to show the map in offline mode

Comment: the links above  are not working , 
i have this post , please see it and tell me if is it a right way .
https://kuamoto.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/myth-1-cant-make-offline-apps/

Comment: Hey amr, I didn't try it yet